# Допустимая ли практика, вызывать методы в конструкторе класса?

Tags: java

Повторюсь, допустимая ли практика вызывать свои методы в конструкторе класса?
Пример:

Я использую метод menu(), в конструторе класса SearchPeople.
(Это вырванный кусок кода, чисто для визуализации вопроса)

```
public class SearchPeople {
    private final String[] peopleList;

    SearchPeople(int size) {
        this.peopleList = new String[size];
        while (true) {
            menu();
        }
    }

    private void menu() {
        System.out.println("\n=== Menu ===\n" +
                "1. Find a person\n" +
                "2. Print all people\n" +
                "0. Exit");
        int choice = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                findPerson();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("=== List of people ===");
                Arrays.stream(peopleList).forEach(System.out::println);
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Incorrect option! Try again.");
        }
}
```

Comment: В такой ситуации, кажется, это не имеет смысла

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy , вы уверены, что "если метод переопределен в потомке, переопределенная версия не вызовется"? Проверьте

Comment: @nikoshi , спасибо. Удалил комментарий.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, это нормальная практика. И всё зависит от ваших  потребностей.
Например, вызов в конструкторе, сеттеров, содержащих проверку вводимых значений:

```
    public NewClass(int a) {
        setA(a);
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        if (a <= 0) {
            this.a = 1;
            return;
        }
        this.a = a;
    }
```

Или вот отрывок кода класса прямоугольника, где в конструктор передаются координаты двух точек, образующих диагональ, а остальные параметры фигуры (длины сторон, периметр, площадь) вычисляются с помощью методов (в том числе статических) вызванных в конструкторе:

```
public class Rectangle implements Polygon {
    private PointImpl A;
    private PointImpl B;
    private PointImpl C;
    private PointImpl D;
    private float length;
    private float width;
    private float perimeter;
    private float area;

    public Rectangle(PointImpl A, PointImpl C) {
        this.A = A;
        this.C = C;
        this.setPointsBandD();
        this.length = calcLength();
        this.width = calcWidth();
        this.perimeter = calcPerimeter();
        this.area = calcArea();
    }
    ...
}
```

Вызов метода - ресурсозатратная операция и поэтому, лучше осуществить какие-либо вычисления или проверки прямо в теле конструктора, а не выносить в отдельный метод, но если этот функционал понадобится не только при создании экземпляра класса, но и в работе других методов или как часть интерфейса класса, то выносим в отдельный метод.

Answer (score 5):

Да, это нормальная практика, если вы внимательны. У кода вызываемого из конструктора, есть особенности.

Метод может быть вызван для не полностью сконструированого объекта:

```
public class MethodCallInConstructor1 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Class().method();
    }

    public static class Class {
        private final int value1;
        private final int value2;
        public Class() {
            System.out.println("Class.Class");
            value1 = 10;
            method();
            value2 = 100;
        }
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("Class.method: value1 " + value1 + ", value2 " + value2);
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac MethodCallInConstructor1.java && java MethodCallInConstructor1
> Class.Class
> Class.method: value1 10, value2 0
> Class.method: value1 10, value2 100
> ```

Поля в классе `Class` обозначены `final`. Нормально предполагать что эти значения неизменны во время работы программы. И это так после того как конструктор завершился. А во время конструирования значение `final`-поля может измениться и это видно всему миру.
**Если вы вызываете метод из конструктора учтите что объект может быть в необычном состоянии.**

Метод производного класса вызывается до конструктора производного класса:

```
public class MethodCallInConstructor2 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Derived();
    }

    public static class Base {
        public Base() {
            System.out.println("Base.Base");
            method();
        }
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("Base.method");
        }
    }

    public static class Derived extends Base {
        public Derived() {
            System.out.println("Derived.Derived");
        }
        @Override
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("Derived.method");
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac MethodCallInConstructor2.java && java MethodCallInConstructor2
> Base.Base
> Derived.method
> Derived.Derived
> ```

В Java конструирование объекта происходит в две стадии: объект распределяется в памяти и заполняется нулями, затем вызывается конструктор.
**Если вы вызываете метод из конструктора базового класса и метод переопределен в наследнике, учтите что объект будет полностью или частично не инициализирован.**

Если при конструировании метод бросит исключение, оператор `new Class(...)` не завершится нормально и объект, например, не будет никуда присвоен. **Если вы бросаете исключение из вызваного метода, то вся сделанная работа по созданию объекта пропадает.**

Ни один из этих пунктов не запрещает вам вызывать методы из конструкторов. Будьте внимательны, пишите длинные комментарии и всё будет хорошо.